# Why UserControl without XAML controls do not inherit properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I had a working user control done in WPF in XAML. Now I have removed the XAML and created the usercontrol with code because I need to inherit from this control. Previosuly I had code like this one on the code using the control:

```
<mc:MyControl Foreground="White">
```

And all the controls inside the MyControl control used this Foreground setting. Now that I've created the control just using C# this is not happening anymore.

Someone know why and how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Utils.Wpf.Chart.Chart"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         SizeChanged="UserControl_SizeChanged">
<Grid>
    <Border Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"  x:Name="DrawArea" Canvas.Background="Transparent" MouseEnter="DrawArea_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="DrawArea_MouseLeave" MouseMove="DrawArea_MouseMove" Cursor="None">
                <Line x:Name="Border1" X1="0" X2="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}" Y1="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}" Y2="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                <Line x:Name="Border2" Y1="0" Y2="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}" X1="0" X2="0" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="CrossValue" Text="[-,-]" Foreground="#EBDE11" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </Canvas>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=MaxYCaption, TargetNullValue=MaxY}" Margin="3,0,6,0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=MinYCaption, TargetNullValue=MinY}" Margin="3,0,6,0"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=MinX, TargetNullValue=MinX}" Margin="3,3,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=MaxX, TargetNullValue=MaxX}" Margin="0,3,3,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is the C#:

```
        _outerGrid = new Grid();
        _border = new Border();
        _innerGrid = new Grid();
        _canvas = new Canvas();
        _line1 = new Line();
        _line2 = new Line();
        _cursorText = new TextBlock();
        _maxXText = new TextBlock();
        _maxYText = new TextBlock();
        _minXText = new TextBlock();
        _minYText = new TextBlock();

        this.Content = _outerGrid;

        _border.Margin = new Thickness(5);
        _border.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        _border.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

        _outerGrid.Children.Add(_border);

        _column1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        _column1.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
        _column2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        _column2.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        _column3 = new ColumnDefinition();
        _column3.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

        _row1 = new RowDefinition();
        _row1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        _row2 = new RowDefinition();
        _row2.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        _row3 = new RowDefinition();
        _row3.Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);

        _innerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(_column1);
        _innerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(_column2);
        _innerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(_column3);

        _innerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(_row1);
        _innerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(_row2);
        _innerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(_row3);

        _border.Child = _innerGrid;

        _canvas.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        _canvas.Cursor = Cursors.None;
        _canvas.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(_canvas_MouseEnter);
        _canvas.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(_canvas_MouseMove);
        _canvas.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(_canvas_MouseLeave);

        Grid.SetColumn(_canvas,1);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(_canvas,2);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(_canvas,2);

        _innerGrid.Children.Add(_canvas);

        _line1.X1 = 0;
        _line1.StrokeThickness = 1;

        Binding x2Binding = new Binding("ActualWidth");
        x2Binding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor) {AncestorType = _canvas.GetType()};
        _line1.SetBinding(Line.X2Property, x2Binding);

        Binding yBinding = new Binding("ActualHeight");
        yBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor) { AncestorType = _canvas.GetType() };
        _line1.SetBinding(Line.Y1Property, yBinding);
        _line1.SetBinding(Line.Y2Property, yBinding);

        _line2.Y1 = 0;
        _line2.X1 = 0;
        _line2.X2 = 0;
        _line2.StrokeThickness = 1;

        Binding y2Binding = new Binding("ActualHeight");
        y2Binding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor) { AncestorType = _canvas.GetType() };
        _line2.SetBinding(Line.Y2Property, x2Binding);

        Binding strokeBinding = new Binding("BorderBrush");
        strokeBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor) { AncestorType = typeof(UserControl) };
        _line2.SetBinding(Shape.StrokeProperty, strokeBinding);

        _cursorText.Text = "[-,-]";
        _cursorText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0xeb, 0xde, 11));
        _cursorText.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        _canvas.Children.Add(_line1);
        _canvas.Children.Add(_line2);
        _canvas.Children.Add(_cursorText);

        _maxYText.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        _maxYText.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        _maxYText.Margin = new Thickness(3, 0, 6, 0);

        Binding maxYBinding = new Binding("MaxYCaption");
        maxYBinding.TargetNullValue = "MaxY";
        maxYBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor) { AncestorType = typeof(UserControl) };
        _maxYText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, maxYBinding);

        _minYText.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        _minYText.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        _minYText.Margin = new Thickness(3, 0, 6, 0);

        Binding minYBinding = new Binding("MinYCaption");
        minYBinding.TargetNullValue = "MinY";
        minYBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor) { AncestorType = typeof(UserControl) };
        _minYText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, minYBinding);

        _maxXText.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        _maxXText.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        _maxXText.Margin = new Thickness(0, 3, 3, 0);

        Binding maxXBinding = new Binding("MaxX");
        maxXBinding.TargetNullValue = "MaxX";
        maxXBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor) { AncestorType = typeof(UserControl) };
        _maxXText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, maxXBinding);

        _minXText.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        _minXText.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        _minXText.Margin = new Thickness(3, 3, 0, 0);

        Binding minXBinding = new Binding("MinX");
        minXBinding.TargetNullValue = "MinX";
        minXBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor) { AncestorType = typeof(UserControl) };
        _minXText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, minXBinding);

        _innerGrid.Children.Add(_maxYText);
        _innerGrid.Children.Add(_maxXText);
        _innerGrid.Children.Add(_minYText);
        _innerGrid.Children.Add(_minXText);

        Grid.SetColumn(_maxXText, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(_minXText, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(_minYText, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(_minXText, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(_maxXText, 2);

        this.SizeChanged += new System.Windows.SizeChangedEventHandler(Chart2_SizeChanged);
```

Comment: How exactly does it make any difference if you define the controls in XAML or C#? If there *is* a difference then you have done something wrong. Also UserControls are never meant to be inherited.

Comment: When XAML is turned into C# code something can happen that makes a difference. Non inheriting is not an option.

Comment: It surely is an option as you are shooting yourself in the foot if you stick to a UserControl when you need a custom control.

Comment: Why I'm shooting myself at the foot?

Comment: UserControls are not meant to provide this kind of functionality, and having having to deal with C# such as the above is the very definition of shooting oneself in the foot.

Comment: Note that in Silverlight UserControls are inheritable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SoMoS - I think what you are talking about is a CustomControl, and not a UserControl. If so, did you apply a control template to your inherited control?

You can read about the differences between custom controls to user controls in here-

http://wangmo.wordpress.com/2007/09/28/user-controls-vs-custom-controls/

http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html

If you will apply a control template to your custom control, you could manage its look just as you would with a User Control with XAML.

Comment: I need to inherit the control to override some property types and methods, not to change the look of the control. I don't care about the look of the control, its a change on the functionality.

Comment: If you don't want to change its look, then why are you designing your control in code? What is your exact problem? that the control's child UI elements do not inherit the background color? I'm not sure anymore what your problem is.

Comment: You cannot inherit from a UserControl if it is designed with XAML because you get an error: cannot be the root of a XAML file because it was defined using XAML.

Comment: Which control are you trying to inherit from? You can inherit from a control if you use a CustomControl and not a UserControl.

Comment: One done by myself. Maybe I will look into the CustomControl latter. Thanks.